# R Custom visual error when in published in web

Tags: r, powerbi

I have the following error, since yesterday my custom visual developed in R (gggplot2 + plotly) looks bad when publishing to the web (axis labels). Before I didn't have that problem. Anyone know how to fix it? Beforehand thank you very much!

[image: How loooks in Power BI desktop]

[image: How looks in web publishing]

```r
('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')
    
############### Library Declarations ###############
libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2");
libraryRequireInstall("plotly")
####################################################

################### Actual code ####################
g=ggplot(data=Values)+ geom_line(aes(x=`Profundidad (m)`, y=`RQD (%)`,color=`Nombre punto`), size=0.6) + 
  geom_point(data=Values,(aes(x=`Profundidad (m)`, y=`RQD (%)`,color=`Nombre punto`,text = paste(`Nombre punto`,'</br></br>Depth (m): ',`Profundidad (m)`,
                                                                                                  '</br>RQD (%): ',
                                                                                                      round(`RQD (%)`,digits=0)))),size=0.01)+
  coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse() + xlab(NULL) +
  ylab("RQD (%)") + theme_bw()+labs(color="")+theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8.5));
#geom_vline(data=Sondaje, aes(xintercept=Prof_Turno),linetype = "dashed")

####################################################

############# Create and save widget ###############
p = ggplotly(g,tooltip = c("text")) %>%layout(hoverlabel=list(font=list(size=10))) %>%
  plotly::config(locale="es",modeBarButtonsToRemove = c("zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d","zoom2d","toggleSpikelines","lasso2d","hoverCompareCartesian","autoScale2d","toggleHover","hoverClosestCartesian","select2d"),displaylogo = FALSE);
internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');
```